# divide UITableView Section as per date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` of which datasource is core data. The core data has one entity with two attributes i.e. **textValue**, **textCreationDate**.

I'm able to fetch these values in `UITableView` as **textValue** in `cell.textLabel.text` and **textCreationDate** in `cell.detailTextLabel.text`

```
NSManagedObject *copies = [self.databaseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [copies valueForKey:@"textcopied"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [copies valueForKey:@"datecopied"];
```

Now I want to divide this table into sections and sections should be created using **textCreationDate**.
For example, I have 5 values in **textValue** with 3 of today's date and 2 of yesterday's date. This should divide the tableView into 2 sections and put **textValues** into corresponding sections.

Comment: Did you have a look at the DateSectionTitles sample project from the Apple developer library (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/datesectiontitles/Introduction/Intro.html) ? That demonstrates exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your viewControllers viewDidLoad method you could prepare your datasource, so that you split the single array into an array of arrays. so in first step sort your self.databaseArray by date and then create for each day a separate array with the entries for that day. now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfSectionInTableView and numberOfRowsInSections you can decide which dayarray you need with which entry.